# Python 3.4.1: Can't Open and Read a local file

Tags: python, python-3.4

```
def functION():
    Source_obj = path.relpath("WebSource\EXAMPLE SOURCE.htm")
    data = Source_obj.read()
```

I am having trouble opening this file while located in a sub-directory directly underneath my Python file... is there a better way to open files from ANY directory on my computer?

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'WebSource\\EXAMPLE SOURCE.htm'
```

I can't read from the file because I get the following error:

```
C:\python34\python.exe G:\Robot\test.py
Process started >>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Robot\test.py", line 118, in <module>
    functION()
  File "G:\Robot\test.py", line 64, in functION
    data = Source_obj.read()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
<<< Process finished. (Exit code 1)
================ READY ================
```

BTW:  The file to be read is just a source file from an HTML Chrome webpage.

### EDIT

I'm looking for more help with the path and wondering why I get the first mentioned Traceback regarding the path

Comment: Why the downvotes on this question?  It includes both code and a traceback.  I wish most newbie questions were written like this one.

Comment: The error message tells you what you need to know.  `data = Source_obj.read()` fails because `'str' object has no attribute 'read'`.  You can conclude that `Source_obj` is a string.  Then you look back and see that `Source_obj` was assigned the result of `path.relpath` function.  Then you go [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath).

Comment: Thanks! I just started learning Python a few days ago and am starting to implement it now

Comment: The read data will remain, yes; the read data is not tied to the file object, open *or* closed.

Comment: @PythonApprentice: and what do you mean by *any directory*? Python won't just search your harddisk.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Lets say I move the folder containing my source to a completely different location... what then?  In reference to the answer StevenRumbalski left:  if I used 'relpath(path, start=os.curdir)' would I just use part of the new directory in place of 'os.curdir'?  Either way it is not working now... see my last edit please.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski:  you may be interested in my last comment... or at least able to provide advice.

Comment: @PythonApprentice: then use an absolute path. It is as simple as that, really.

Comment: What `os.path.relpath()` does here is little more than add `.\` in front of your path, making it relative to the *current working directory*. That's usually not a good idea; you really want to use an absolute path or derive an absolute path from another known file location.

Comment: @MartijnPieters:  thanks... I guess I'll just have to mess around with it for a while (and I don't have enough reputation to chat yet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`os.path.relpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) returns a **string**, not an open file object. You'll need to open a file first; use the [`open()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open):

```
def functION():
    Source_obj = path.relpath(r"WebSource\EXAMPLE SOURCE.htm")
    with open(Source_obj) as fileobj:
        data = fileobj.read()
```

`with` here treats the file object as a context manager; when the indented codeblock under the statement is exited (either because the code completed or an exception occurred), the file object will automatically be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Source_obj` is just a string, not a file.

```
def functION():
    Source_obj = path.relpath("WebSource\EXAMPLE SOURCE.htm")
    with open(Source_obj) as f:
        data = f.read()
```

By `open()`-ing it you can read from the file. Using the `with` context manager, the file will be properly closed for you when you leave that block of code.